# Arabic/Polyglossia/Bidi incompatibility with `abnt` package

Tags: sectioning, polyglossia, arabic, bidi, abnt

Using `bidi` redefines chapter headings and also figure counters with `chngcntr` back to the default `book` class behavior. I tried to change the order of the packages, even in the `.sty` file, to no avail.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{abnt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[locale=mashriq]{arabic}
\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Introduction}

\chapter{Figure tests}
\textarabic{\today}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\addtocounter{figure}{9}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You say this is an error, but this code compiles without error for me. I assume there's a problem with the output? Can you explain what that is?

Comment: Adding `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}` makes the figure numbering not dependent on `chapter` which seems to be what `abnt` does when `polyglossia` isn't loaded. Is that what you want?

Comment: @AlanMunn, the problem is with `bidi`, not `polyglossia` itself. Besides the figure counters (`\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}` is indeed included in `abnt.sty`), which are a minor annoyance (new types of floats aren't affected), chapter headings, which had previously been modified by the class, come back to their default `book` class when using `bidi`.

Comment: Yes, of course, but nothing in your question explains any of that. (And it's not an error, just an incompatibility.)  You're expecting people to know exactly what `abnt` does and instantly notice when compiling your example all the things that are different. Given that `abnt` is itself a very special style, combined with the fact that the vast majority of users of `bidi` would have no need to use `abnt`, you're asking an awful lot.  `bidi` indeed changes a lot of things, because it needs to allow RTL in all of the sectioning commands, captions etc.

Comment: @AlanMunn, you're right. I have modified the question to make it clear.

Comment: I've added a tentative answer. But I suspect there are more things that will need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

It's still not totally clear from your question what all changes, but looking into `abnt.sty` it seems it mainly makes two changes to the formatting of chapters. So I think the following will do what you want.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{abnt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[locale=mashriq]{arabic}
\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    %\vspace*{50\p@}% <----------------- Space from top of page to Chapter #
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \thechapter\ \enspace %\. <-- Chapter #
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@% <-------------- Space between Chapter # and title
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak% <------------------ Chapter title
        \vskip 40\p@% <------------------ Space between chapter title and first paragraph
}}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    %\vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering
        \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
}}
\makeatother
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Introduction}

\chapter{Figure tests}
\textarabic{\today}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\addtocounter{figure}{9}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```